# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError in Directive with Angular

Tags: css, angular, angular-directive

After I get all the hate, I know there's a thread about this problem but I haven't managed to find a solution for my problem. I'm a rookie.
What I wanted to do was to change the nav header background only when the user is in a particular route, so I created a directive in which I retrieve the current url and then I styled the nav header with setElementStyle. For that I'm comparing if the current url matches a particular url that I store in a variable.
The app is working fine but I still get that error.

This is my directive:

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, Renderer, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationStart, NavigationEnd, NavigationError, NavigationCancel, RoutesRecognized } from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';

@Directive({
  selector: '[styled]',
})
export class StyledDirective implements OnInit {

  constructor(public el: ElementRef, public renderer: Renderer, public _router: Router) {
    renderer.setElementStyle(el.nativeElement, 'color', '#212121');
    renderer.setElementStyle(el.nativeElement, 'backgroundColor', 'rgb(247, 247, 247)');
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    const profileUrl = "/app/userprofile";
    this._router.events
    .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationStart)
    .subscribe((event:NavigationStart) => {
      if (event.url == profileUrl) {
        return this.el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = '#ffffff';
      }
      else {
        return this.el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(247, 247, 247)';
      }
    });
    this._router.events
    .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationStart)
    .subscribe((event:NavigationStart) => {
      if (event.url == profileUrl) {
        return this.el.nativeElement.style.color = "#03A9F4";
      }
      else {
        return this.el.nativeElement.style.color = '#212121';
      }
    });
    }
}
```

Probably its not the best code ever but that's how I tried to resolve my problem, and probably there's a more elegant solution for this. Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: I tested you directive and it works with no error. I would though remove return in front of this.el.native.... and group both stylings (bg color and color) in the same if() else(). Also I think it's kind of heavy, would've it be easier to just change color from profile component with some css ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Vega Like I said, maybe there's a more elegant solution to my problem than creating a directive, but I'm just learning. So, maybe you could guide me on how to change the color from profile component with css, please.

Comment: If you're curios why this error occurs read [Everything you need to know about the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer this way

First inject the `Router` in constructor, then return a function according to route

```
constructor(private router: Router) {}
 getRoute(){
       if (this.router.url === '/client'){
         return "client";
       }
   }
```

in your html

`<header [ngClass]="getRoute()">`

and in css

`header.client{background-color:yellow}`